# how do you make the return here

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, asynchronous

**General Functionality**

```
async function fname(var1, var2) {
  var store = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) {
      //.....read function......
      //return the value;
      return data
  });

  console.log("output", store) //"has the required data 

  return store; //returning Promise Pennding
}
```

I can't return the stored value and it  is returning Promise pending

Answer (score 1):

How you would do it is with the `resolve(data)` method. You can read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-promise-resolve-method/ and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise.

The code example would be:

```js
async function fname(var1, var2) {
  var store = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) {
      //.....read function......
      //return the value;

      resolve(data)
  });

  console.log("output", store) // has the required data 

  return store; //returning Promise Pending
}
```

Don't hesitate to comment if you have any questions. :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the data

```
var store = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(data); //Returns the data
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

a `Promise` returns data by calling it's resolve method with the data, so instead of `return data`

```
resolve(data)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Answer (score 0):

You could use `resolve` instead of `return` in promise

```
async function fname(var1, var2) {
  var store = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) {
      //.....read function......
      //return the value;
      resolve(data)
  });

  console.log("output", store) //"has the required data 

  return store; //returning Promise Pennding
}
```